# Codeigniter email library not sending on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I know that this is already multiple answered here, but all these answers did not helped me with my problem.
Because it is the simpliest way for testing, I use the mail protocol, and work on my local xampp machine.
Here is my relevant code:

```
<?php
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->initialize(array(
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'validate' => TRUE
);

$this->email->from($this->config->item('demo@example.org', 'Test');
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->subject('ServerManager Registration');
$this->email->message($mail_content);
if ($this->email->send()) {
    // This becomes triggered when sending
}
?>
```

The variables $mail_content and $email are correctly spelled and working.

I enabled mail() logging in my xampp environment, so I am able to show you the log triggered:

```
mail() on [C:\xampp\htdocs\core\system\libraries\Email.php:1553]: To: ***@live.de -- Headers: User-Agent: CodeIgniter Date: Thu, 13 Jun 2013 18:14:46 +0200 From: "ServerManager" <your@domain.com> Return-Path: <your@domain.com> Reply-To: "your@domain.com" <your@domain.com> X-Sender: your@domain.com X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3 (Normal) Message-ID: <51b9eff6ab7bb@domain.com> Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_51b9eff6ab7c2"
```

Comment: XAMPP does not come with a mail server which is required to send mail. Do you have some kind of mail server running on the machine hosting xampp? Also try using `echo $this->email->print_debugger();` to check for errors.

Comment: Isn't the standard mail() function already in the standard php installation? The debugging function does not show something that looks like an error, only my entered informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be caused due to the usage of `$this->config->item`. Try this

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->initialize(array(
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'validate' => TRUE,
));

$this->email->from('demo@example.org', 'Test');
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->subject('ServerManager Registration');
$this->email->message($mail_content);

if ($this->email->send()) {
    // This becomes triggered when sending
    echo("Mail Sent");
}else{
    echo($this->email->print_debugger()); //Display errors if any
}
```

P.S In you code `)` were missing in two places

#### Update:

Checked the script by sending mail to **Gmail**, **Yahoo** and **Rediff mail** accounts from `localhost`. Mail was delivered in **Gmail**(Was present in `spam` folder). As for **Yahoo** and **Rediff mail**, the email has not been delivered yet(15 mins have passed) to `inbox` or `spam/trash` folder

Comment: They may be missing because i cutted out some not important db queries. It does not work without the config request, too.

Comment: any error messages? I checked the script in my localhost and it works fine.

Comment: no, but then my host might fail. I will try it on another server, and will comment than again.

Comment: When you execute the script does `Mail Sent` being displayed but mail is not delivered?

Comment: Of course, it is saying "Result: Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail ....."

Comment: did you check for the mail in `junk` or `spam` folder in your mail account?

Comment: Yes, and it even want delivered to gmail. I really think the pain is on my server.

Comment: After doing all as told by curious_coder, you need local smtp server which is freely available get it from here: https://test-mail-server-tool.soft112.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->load->library('email');
 public function mail()
    {
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $data = '';
        $email_body = $this->load->view('promo',$data,true);
        $this->email->from('demo@example.org', 'Contact request');          
        $this->email->to('demo.com');
        $this->email->subject('Test');
        $this->email->message($email_body);
        $this->email->send();
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
```

try this one